# PHP preg_replace - Replacing all instances of various URLs from sentences

Tags: php, regex

I'm having a real headache to craft the proper php preg_replace code to remove all possible URLs terms from text contents... I want to prevent spammers from even mentioning their URLs when posting contents/comments on my website (which will host a lot of contibutors).

Examples of types of URLs terms:

```
https://www.example.com
http://www.example.com
www.example.com
subdomain.example.com
www.subdomain.example.com
example.com
```

Initial paragraph:

> https://www.subdomain.example.com This is the FIRST inner dummy
>   sentence. https://www.subdomain.example.com This is the SECOND inner
>   dummy sentence. https://www.subdomain.example.com

Should convert to this paragraph:

> This is the FIRST inner dummy sentence. This is the SECOND inner dummy
>   sentence.

.

I think the easiest way would be to match the last .tld (dot tld) and anything before the .tld (dot tld). Please kindly understand that the tld can be a .net or .anything ...

I was able to find a code to remove `<a href="/">link</a>` as per below:

```
function remove_html_link($link) {
$end = preg_replace('#<a.*?>.*?</a>#i', '', $link);
return $end;
}
```

But how can one craft a preg_replace for **PLAIN URLs (not linked i.e. normal text)** please?

Thanking you all in advance for a solution!

> **So the final best working code snippet for my case is from:**
>
> @user3783243 - For specific/updated list of TLDs
>
> `"/(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)?[a-z.\/\d-]+\.(com|net|org)\b/"`
>
> user bubble... or bumble... - For all TLDs
>
> `"/\S+\.[a-z]+ */"`
>
> Thank you so much everyone for your help, I wasn't expecting solutions so fast!

Cheers,
Bertlio.

Comment: Maybe `(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)?[a-z.\/\d-]+\.(com|net|org)\b` and make the last capture group every TLD https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

Comment: Thanks for your help @user3783243, it's working great! The only inconvenience is that it relies on the list of TLDs... I'm not too keen to update the list every time but it definitely works for popular TLDs! OR If one wants to blacklist only specific spammy TLDs!

Comment: `"/\S+\.[a-z]+ */"` from user bubble... or bumble... (he/she deleted her own comment) Works great too in my case! Thank you for the code snippet!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php



$data1='https://www.example.com';
$data2='http://www.example.com';
$data3='www.example.com';
$data4='www.subdomain.example.com';



$text = $data1.' This is the FIRST inner dummy sentence ';
$text .= $data2.' This is the SECOND inner dummy sentence ';
$text .= $data3.' This is the THIRD inner dummy sentence ';
$text .= $data4.' This is the FORTH inner dummy sentence ';

$string = preg_replace('/\b((https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i', ' ', $text);



echo $string;
```

The above code will remove the types of url i have set in the variables from any sentece you have.

The output is : *This is the FIRST inner dummy sentence This is the SECOND inner dummy sentence This is the THIRD inner dummy sentence This is the FORTH inner dummy sentence*

Comment: Thanks for the help @pr1nc3, it's working except for these formats: subdomain.example.com and example.com . the ftp/file are a nice addition.